# Compute (x+yCx)%mod

Tags: c++, optimization, algorithm, combinatorics

I want to compute, as quickly as possible,

$$ \dfrac{(x+y)!}{x!y!} \mod m $$

with \$x,y \le 10^6\$ and a prime \$m=10^9+7\$ (called `mod` in my code).

My current approach, computing

$$ \left(\mathtt{Prod}(y+1, y+x) \mod m\right) \cdot \left(\mathtt{InverseMod}(\mathtt{factMod}(x) \mod m)\right) $$

is too slow.  Here is the implementation:

```
   static inline ll powmod(unsigned a, unsigned b){
  register ll x=1,y=a;
  while(b){
    if(b&1){
      x*=y; if(x>=MOD)x%=MOD;
    }
    y*=y; if(y>=MOD)y%=MOD;
    b>>=1;
  }
  return x;
} 

static inline ll InverseMod(ll n){
  return powmod(n,MOD-2);
}

static inline ll prodMod(ll minx,ll maxx){
    for(unsigned i=minx+1; i<=maxx; i++){
      minx*=i; if(minx>=MOD)minx%=MOD;
    }
  return minx;
}

static inline ll factMOD(unsigned n){
  register ll ans0=1,ans1=1;register unsigned i,m;
  if(n&1){
    for(i=1,m=(n+1)>>1; i<m; i++){
      ans0*=(i<<1); if(ans0>=MOD)ans0%=MOD;
      ans1*=((i<<1)+1); if(ans1>=MOD)ans1%=MOD;
    }
    return ans0*ans1%MOD;
  }else{
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++){
      ans0*=i; if(ans0>=MOD)ans0%=MOD;
    }
    return ans0;
  }
}

static inline ll chemin(ll x, ll y){
  return (prodMod(x+1,x+y) *
      InverseMod(factMOD(y)))%MOD;
}
```

I've found and implemented [Wilson's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem). The `factMODWilson` function is the one to call to compute (n!) % MOD when MOD-n is little against n, but here it's not the case.

Does someone know an efficient approach when n=1e6 and MOD=1e9+7?

```
ll factMODWilson(ll n){ //n! % MOD efficient when MOD-n<n
   ll res=1,i;
   for(i=1; i<MOD-n; i++){
     res*=i;
     if(res>=MOD)res%=MOD;
   }
   res=InverseMod(res);   
    if(!(n&1))
      res= -res +MOD;
  }
  return res%MOD;
}
```

Comment: Using assembly is faster than using plain C++.

Comment: Maybe you can generalize the prime powers approach: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/14456/factorial-algorithm-more-efficient-than-naive-multiplication

Comment: @user3725053 : In this case, using the right algorithm for the job is faster. Translating the code presented here into assembly by hand will not speed up its execution by a factor that's relevant to the problem.

Comment: @YvesDaoust interesting approach for factorials, but it doesn't seems simple to fit this approach to a factorial modular.

Comment: If x >= y, (x+y)!/(x!)(y)! = (x+1)(x+2)...(x+y)/y!
If x < y,  (x+y)!/(x!)(y)! = (y+1)(y+2)...(y+x)/x!

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about the timing problem? chemin(1e6, 1e6) is computed in about 0.02 s on my MacBook. Btw, what does "chemin" stand for?

Comment: Anyway it's too slow. I've heard of another algo for factMod based on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem but I don't see the logic

Comment: the problem is a generalisation of the Euler 15 problem (where x=y=20)

Comment: I'm interested in the optimisation of the factMOD function. Do you know the algo based on the Wilson's theorem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18996/discussion-between-martin-r-and-bilbo).

Comment: I've heard of another algo for factMod based on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem but I don't see the logic. Do you know the algo using the Wilson's theorem?

Comment: @rcgldr don't forget the overflow problem: here 1e5<x,y<1e6 and mod=1e9+7 and the language is c++.

Comment: @bilbo - I only meant to show that some terms can be eliminated, for example, if x > y, you eliminate x! from the numerator and denominator, so that's 2 x fewer terms to calculate.

Comment: @rcgldr if you read my code carefully that's what I do in the prodMod and the factMOD functions excepted the choice of min(x,y) and max(x,y) which is in the chemin(x,y) function call. I think I have to find a new math approach for factMod using modular arithmetics.

Comment: @bilbo - ok. I assume you're using powmod(... , mod-2) to invert a number. It might be faster to use (link) : [extended Euclid algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Computing_multiplicative_inverses_in_modular_structures)

Comment: @rcgldr the modulo must be coprime with x,y,x+y because (n!)%mod=0 if mod<=n or a factor of mod is <=n, so I consider in the problem that the modulo is a prime. I have benchmarked extEuclid algo and powmod(...,mod-2) the timings are similar.

Comment: @bilbo -I realized that and redid my comment. Since the modulus is prime (1e9+7), then all numbers < the modulus are co-prime. The worse case scenario for exEuclid in this case is 564400443, which takes 36 loops, and the inverse of 564400443 is 618082898. powmod should max out at 30 loops.

Comment: @bilbo - There may be some cases where you could use | if(x>=MOD) | if  (x < 2*MOD) | x -= MOD | else | x %= MOD, to reduce usage of %. I don't think Wilson's theorem will help since x and y don't have to be prime numbers.

Comment: @rcgldr your modulo reduce usage new idea may be of interest. I think there is a big math trick with modulo and factorials but I don't figure it. I haven't the time for unrolling the loop for even n in the factmod function (in the case of odd n it is 10% faster).

Comment: Since y <= 1e6, you could calculate the product of a series of terms before doing modulo. Like | long long i, prod, fact; | fact = 1 | ... | prod = 1 | while(prod <= 9223372036854 && i < n) | prod *= i++; | prod %= mod | fact = (fact * prod)%mod. Also unsigned long long math should be quicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my system, Windows 7 64 bit, Intel 2600K 3.4ghz, in 64 bit mode, this example is about 3 times faster. This code was compiled with Visual Studio Express 2013. Update - in prodMod and factMod I changed prod = 1ull; to prod = i++; for one less loop. 2nd update - made function names consistent, ProdMod constant good for <= 2e6, and FactMod constant (this was changed) good for <= 1e6. No significant change to overall time.

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
typedef unsigned long long uint64_t;
#define MOD (1000000007ull)
static clock_t dwTimeStart;     // clock values
static clock_t dwTimeStop;

static inline uint64_t PowMod(uint64_t a, uint64_t b){
register uint64_t x=1,y=a;
    while(b){
        if(b&1){
            x*=y; if(x>=MOD)x%=MOD;
        }
        y*=y; if(y>=MOD)y%=MOD;
        b>>=1;
    }
    return x;
} 

static inline uint64_t InverseMod(uint64_t n){
    return PowMod(n,MOD-2);
}

static inline uint64_t ProdMod(uint64_t minx, uint64_t maxx){
uint64_t fact = minx;
uint64_t prod;
uint64_t i = (minx+1);
    while(i<=maxx){
        prod = i++;
        while(prod <= 9223372036854ull && i <= maxx)
            prod*=i++;
        prod%=MOD;
        fact=(fact*prod)%MOD;
    }
    return fact;
}

static inline uint64_t FactMod(uint64_t n){
register uint64_t fact=1;
register uint64_t prod;
register uint64_t i;
    i = 1;
    while(i <= n){
        prod = i++;
        while(prod <= 18446744073708ull && i <= n)
            prod*=i++;
        prod%=MOD;
        fact=(fact*prod)%MOD;
    }
    return fact;
}

static inline uint64_t CheMin(uint64_t x, uint64_t y){
    return (ProdMod(x+1,x+y) * InverseMod(FactMod(y)))%MOD;
}

int main()
{
uint64_t i, j;
    dwTimeStart = clock();
    for(j = 999800; j <= 1000000; j++)
        i = CheMin(j, j);
    dwTimeStop = clock();
    std::cout << "Number of ticks    " << (dwTimeStop-dwTimeStart) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Answer             " << i << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19049/discussion-on-answer-by-rcgldr-compute-xycxmod).

Answer (score 2):

Just some further optimization attempts: The important thing is to mimimize the number of modular reductions. rcgldr's approach tries to do it dynamically, which doesn't seem to be worth it. With numbers somewhere below 2e6, you can multiply exactly three of them; no need to test anything.

Their product must be reduced, then it gets multiplied to the result, which in turn has to be reduced in order to be ready for the next multiplication. This leaves us with 2 reductions every 3 numbers.

I believe, we can do better, namely just 1 reduction for 2 numbers (warning, Java code ahead!):

```
private long prodMod(int i, int j) {
    long result = 1;
    long p = mulMod(i, j);
    while (i<j-2) {
        assert p == mulMod(i, j);
        result = mulMod(result, p);
        p += j-- - i++ - 1;

        if (p>MOD) p -= MOD;
        assert p < MOD;
    }

    assert i <= j;
    while (i<=j) result = mulMod(result, i++);
    return result;
}
```

Here, `mulMod` does exactly what its name says. In every step, `result *= i++ * j--` gets computed using modular arithmetic. Once in a blue moon, `p` must be reduced.

This looks fine, but is not fast, probably due to pipelining issues. The value of `result` gets change in every iteration, the division takes ages, and time gets wasted due to data dependencies. With some accumulators for intermediate results it got way faster

```
private long prodMod(int i, int j) {
    long acc0 = 1;
    long acc1 = 1;
    long acc2 = 1;
    long acc3 = 1;
    long acc4 = 1;
    long acc5 = 1;
    long p = mulMod(i, j);
    while (i<j-20) { // 20 is surely big enough for this unrolling
        assert p == mulMod(i, j);
        acc0 = mulMod(acc0, p);
        p += j-- - i++ - 1;

        assert p == mulMod(i, j);
        acc1 = mulMod(acc1, p);
        p += j-- - i++ - 1;

        assert p == mulMod(i, j);
        acc2 = mulMod(acc2, p);
        p += j-- - i++ - 1;

        assert p == mulMod(i, j);
        acc3 = mulMod(acc3, p);
        p += j-- - i++ - 1;

        assert p == mulMod(i, j);
        acc4 = mulMod(acc4, p);
        p += j-- - i++ - 1;

        assert p == mulMod(i, j);
        acc5 = mulMod(acc5, p);
        p += j-- - i++ - 1;

        if (p>MOD) p -= MOD;
        assert p < MOD;
    }

    assert i <= j;
    long result = 1;
    result = mulMod(result, acc0);
    result = mulMod(result, acc1);
    result = mulMod(result, acc2);
    result = mulMod(result, acc3);
    result = mulMod(result, acc4);
    result = mulMod(result, acc5);
    while (i<=j) result = mulMod(result, i++);
    return result;
}
```

On my Core i5-2400 it takes 4.5 s for 2000 iterations (Java needs some warmup, measuring just 200 iterations would make no sense).

### Caching

For caching every 1024 steps, add

```
private static final int CACHE_SCALE = 10;
private final long[] cache = new long[(2_000_000 >> CACHE_SCALE) + 1];
```

rename the old method to `uncachedProdMod`, and add

```
private long prodMod(int min, int max) {
    final int hi = (max >> CACHE_SCALE) << CACHE_SCALE;
    long result = uncachedProdMod(hi, max);
    int lo = (min >> CACHE_SCALE) << CACHE_SCALE;
    if (lo < min) lo += 1 << CACHE_SCALE;
    result = mulMod(result, uncachedProdMod(min, lo-1));
    result = mulMod(result, cachedProdMod(lo, hi-1));
    return result;
}

private long cachedProdMod(int min, int max) {
    long result = 1;
    while (min < max) {
        final int next = min + (1 << CACHE_SCALE);
        final int index = min >> CACHE_SCALE;
        long prod = cache[index];
        if (prod == 0) {
            prod = uncachedProdMod(min, next-1);
            cache[index] = prod;
        }
        result = mulMod(result, prod);
        min = next;
    }
    return result;
}
```

At index `i`, the cache stores the product of all numbers between `i * 2**CACHE_SCALE` and `(i+1) * 2**CACHE_SCALE - 1` (and 0 denotes an uninitialized slot).

"Memoization" would be probably a better term for this.

Comment: Java=bytecode=1.5GB per process but of good use for arbitrary precision. Python is faster, C++ further more. why using it for modular arithmetics???

Comment: @bilbo What 1.5GB??? In general, Python is way slower, but Java's `BigInteger` is not its strongest part. I wrote it in Java as it's my strongly preferred language. I'd bet a C programmer can read it easily. I guess, my algorithm is faster, given that it makes more iterations per second on a weaker CPU.

Comment: On some profilers 1.5GB is the RAM consumption one can see at startup of any Java software. At my stupefaction your code recoded in C++ is faster than all the previous I've tested for the problem at this time: 1.88s congratulations for your optimization.

Comment: @bilbo I guess that's the virtual memory initially allocated, you can tune it down with something like `-Xmx500M`. The default is based on total memory available and Java is memory hungry, but I've never cared. I'm glad to hear that the optimization is good, but is it good enough?

Comment: unfortunately, it's not enough (time required is 0.9s)

Comment: @bilbo Maybe a more complicated algorithm would do, I tried and failed. But precomputation or caching is a sure bet. For caching: Look if the interval `min, max` contains one of more intervals of the form `n*K, (n+1)*K` (with e.g. `K=1024`). Have an array `int[2e6/K]` initialized with zeros. Look at index `n` and if you find a non-zero, you saved `K` operations. Otherwise compute the value and store it.

Comment: Is it significative in time to use a segmented cache?

Comment: @bilbo No, but for caching this is the simplest I can come up with and it only adds a negligible time in case of a miss. It allows to tune the memory consumption and is very simple to implement (complete factorial precomputation is even a bit simpler).

Comment: I'm interested in your caching algo.

Comment: @bilbo Wasn't the description clear enough? Btw., when testing the speed, did you implement `factMod` via my `prodMod`?

Comment: I've been busy on other projects, and yes I've implemented factMod with your prodMod.

Comment: My caching version lead to a speed-up factor of over 100 when testing 2000 examples. As expected.

Comment: I've just tested it, don't understand the mixed approach dichotomy like in prodMod nor any logic in the 2 cached prodMod and answers are wrong even for (x,y)=1,3 2,4 5,3

Comment: @bilbo Each interval `min..max` gets split into three, so that the inner part can use the cache. My very messy code is [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4971686/published/maaartin/cr/BinomialMod.java). There may be errors, I only tested it near 1e6, but I'm sure, it's nothing fundamental. One day I may clean it up and post for CR, but not now.

Answer (score 1):

First you can get your math to work a little so you have less work to do.

If we have \$x<y\$, and we know that:

\$(x+y)! = 1•2•3•...•(y-1)(y)(y+1)...(y+x-1)(y+x) = y!(y+1)...(y+x)\$

Then you have:

\$\frac{y!(y+1)...(y+x)}{x!y!}=\frac{(y+1)...(y+x)}{x!}\$

So you have a lot less work yo do, given that \$x<y\$.

Comment: If you read my code attentively your idea is what I've implemented in my code. I think the improvement to find is in math modular arithmetics in the computation of (n!)%mod and of (y+1,y+x)%mod